# Как происходит подключение двух клиентов по протоколу P2P?

Tags: сеть, ip, p2p

Как именно происходит подключение? Все примеры кода которые я находил - будут работать лишь на локальном хосте, если я правильно понимаю.
Есть сервер, есть 2 клиента. Оба хотят друг с другом соединиться. Сервер шлет адреса обоим - первому - адрес второго, второму - адрес первого. Соединение устанавливается. Но как это работает в глобальной сети?
У меня есть некоторый IP - он динамический, мне его выдает провайдер. Сервер отсылает мой ip моему собеседнику. Как этот собеседник подключится зная мой ip ? У него нет маршрута до меня. Каким образом я получу запрос на соединение, зная лишь его ip адрес. Если бы было так все просто я мог бы коннектиться к чему угодно. Хоть убейте, я много чего прочитал, не могу разобраться. Ведь если оно так сказочно просто работает, то я могу просто, не отключая компьютер от сети сделать сервер и иметь к нему доступ из любой точки мира,узнав, какой ip мне выдал провайдер

Comment: _Если бы было так все просто я мог бы коннектиться к чему угодно._ Ну, так оно в общем-то и есть, что в этом факте смущает? _я могу просто, не отключая компьютер от сети сделать сервер и иметь к нему доступ из любой точки мира,узнав, какой ip мне выдал провайдер_. Опять же, что Вас в этой идее так удивляет? (IP должен быть "белым", конечно)

Comment: @Yaant Так удивляет то, что оно так не работает, разве нет? Зачем нужен тогда белый IP если и с динамическим все прекрасно работает?

Comment: Динамический IP - чаще всего как раз белый. Вот с серым динамическим IP оно работать не будет.

Comment: @Yaant https://losst.ru/kak-uznat-ip-adres-linux
Вот тут описаны типы ip адресов и рассказано про некоторую NAT. Т.е, вы хотите сказать, что я могу смело написать простенький сервер, развернуть его на своем внешнем ip и он будет досутпен всем ?

Comment: Ну да, если этот внешний IP - действительно внешний, а не серый (за провайдерским NAT'ом).

Comment: @Yaant Ну, по всей видимости мой интернет за провайдерским NAT. Я раздаю интернет с мобильного телефона на компьютер. Оба этих устройства имеют одинаковый внешний IP. Т.е по сути я не могу развернуть сервер на внешнем ip и достучаться до него из любой точки мира, так? 
Просто если оно так и есть, тогда непонятно, почему P2P может достучаться до конретного устройства

Comment: Не факт. Провайдер может давать и белый IP, но телефон при раздаче интернета создает свой собственный NAT. Если найдете способ настроить его так, чтобы пробрасывать конкретный порт на компьютер, то будет работать (но подозреваю, что для этого потребуется рут на телефоне). Точно так же и к P2P-клиенту, находящемуся за NATом другой клиент не сможет подключиться без специальных ухищрений (методы NAT punching. как правило, требуют наличия дополнительного сервера, с белым IP).